# How to create xml element and add nodeValue on IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, web

I'm getting js error on IE10 trying to create an xml node and add value to nodeValue.

**Error:**

```
This operation can not be performed with a node of type ELEMENT.
```

**Code:**

```
var displayValueElement = this.properties.createElement("Property");

if ($.browser.msie)
{
    displayValueElement.nodeValue = "some value"; //error is here
}
```

The code works on Chrome and Firefox but IE has to use nodeValue.

```
displayValueElement.textContent = displayValue;
```

Note: this.properties are xml document that is returned from parseXML()

Thanks in advance, please let me know if need more clarification.

Answer (score 1):

I guess I can resort to using jQuery rather than raw javascript...

```
$(displayValueElement).text(displayValue);
```

Comment: In raw javascript append a textNode : `displayValueElement.appendChild(this.properties.createTextNode('some value'));`